# Link error in DevC++ not in codepad.org

Tags: compiler-errors

I am learning C++ and need some help with compile error messages. I have some code... http://codepad.org/ncGTYWew.

When I compile in DevC++, I get this output:
`22 C:\Dev-Cpp\Program Files\linkedListType.h template-id operator<< <>' forstd::basic_ostream >& operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, const linkedListType&)' does not match any template declaration`

In codepad it seems to compile fine.
Prior to this compile, both codepad and DevC++ requested I insert '<>' after the operator<< declaration in Line 22.

Can someone explain why DevC++ does not recognize the template? Did I put the '<>' in the wrong spot? Why would codepad not have a problem with it?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use code::blocks instead of dev-cpp; five years ago that do not update and the new standard 0xC++ I believe that neither supports it.

Comment: Thank you. That settles that then.